# Writing unit test for ASP.NET MVC Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, unit-testing, asp.net-identity

My customers controller looks like this:

```
public class CustomersController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public CustomersController()
    {
    }

    public CustomersController(ApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

How do I write a unit test that creates a user? `UserManager` class is missing on the UnitTesting side.

```
[TestClass]
public class StoreUnitTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void CreateUserTest()
    {
        User user = new User()
        {
            FirstName = "Bill",
            LastName = "Gates",
            UserName = "billg@microsoft.com",
            LoweredUserName = "billg@microsoft.com",
            Email = "billg@microsoft.com",
            LoweredEmail = "billg@microsoft.com"                    
        };

        // UserManager is missing!
        IdentityResult result = UserManager.Create(user, "password");

        Assert.IsTrue(result.Succeeded);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to test your controller? Or are you wanting to test your ApplicationUserManager? And if you wanted to test your ApplicationUserManager, then why are you showing us the controller code?

Comment: You are using a library that your unit test does not have. It goes outside the scope of your unit test. It is designed to test YOUR function logic. You will have to mock the usermanager instance or you can use DI. Check this out. https://alastairchristian.com/mocking-asp-net-identity-2-usermanager-methods-b740c703b580

Comment: @manson: I need to test the full process of creating user, then billing data associated to the user, then webservice id associated to the user and delete everything from the db before leaving the test.

Comment: Interesting article @LinkedList but it does not add a new user, it simply gets one from the list. Please add the answer with the complete code of the `CreateUserTest()`.